# Print the loop index in Meteor.js templates

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a list of objects in meteorjs which I am iterating in meteorjs templates like

```
{{#each objects}}
{{/each}}
```

In the template I want to print the number of the loop iteration. That is, if the length of the objects list is 100 I want to print the numbers from 1 to 100 in the template. How can I do this?

Comment: Is `objects` an array, a cursor, or an Object?

Comment: It is an array of objects

Comment: All the answer so far are correct but in the scenario of editing 1 row, it triggers the rendering for all the rows which is very inefficient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do this at the moment without giving in an index in your helper, i.e

```
Template.yourtemplatename.object_with_index = function() {
    var objects = Template.yourtemplatename.objects();

    for(var i = 0; i=objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i].index = i;
    }

    return objects;
}
```

Then do:

```
{{#each object_with_index}}
    <p>This is number {{index}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Not the prettiest way, but other variations would basically do the same thing under the hood (e.g if you used a `map`)

Comment: I think it should be `objects[i].index = i;` in the loop.

Comment: Yup thats right! Updated it with that

Comment: thanx man, it works and it shuld be `objects[i].index=i+1` because index always starts with 1

Comment: I think there's an error in the loop:

    `for(var i = 0; i=objects.length; i++)`

Shouldn't it be:

    `for(var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)`

?

Comment: This code works with `{{#each each_path_with_index 'objects'}}` and is registered globally. Also adds `humanIndex` to give you a 1-indexed counter.

`Template.registerHelper('each_path_with_index', function(keyPath) {
    var objects = _.getPath(this, keyPath);

    _.each(objects, function(element, i, list) {
      objects[i].index = i;
      objects[i].humanIndex = i + 1;
    });

    return objects;
});`

Comment: This did not work for me, saying _.getPath is not a function (yes the underscore package is intalled) so I made my helper in the same spirit but with jquery, here it is : ```UI.registerHelper('addIndex', function(thatArray) {
  if (thatArray && thatArray.length) {
    $.each(thatArray, function (position, thatObject) {
      thatObject.index = position;
      thatArray[position] = thatObject;
    });
    return thatArray;
  }
});```

Answer (score 8):

If you objects is a cursor, you can use its [map](http://docs.meteor.com/#map) method:

```
Template.yourtemplatename.objects = YourCollection.find().map(function(document, index){
    document.index = index;
    return document;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a global helper that add an index to an array :

```
UI.registerHelper('addIndex', function(thatArray) {
  if (thatArray && thatArray.length) {
    $.each(thatArray, function (position, thatObject) {
      thatObject.index = position;
      thatArray[position] = thatObject;
    });
    return thatArray;
  }
});
```

and then you call it like that :

```
{{#each addIndex arrayWithoutIndex}}
  The current value is at this index number : {{index}}
{{/each}}
```